# Sending raw WNS notifications using message attributes

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, wns

I am attempting to send a raw notification to WNS by setting message attributes, but it appears that a toast notification is being sent instead.

Here is the C# code I'm using to build the publish request.

```
var request = new PublishRequest()
{
    TopicArn = TOPIC_ARN,
    Message = "Test Message",
    MessageAttributes = new Dictionary<string, MessageAttributeValue>()
    {
        { "AWS.SNS.MOBILE.WNS.Type", new MessageAttributeValue() { StringValue = "wns/raw", DataType = "String" } }
    }
};
```

From what I can tell, I am setting the [X-WNS-Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465435.aspx#pncodes_x_wns_type) correctly using SNS
[Message Attributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMessageAttributes.html), but the notification is still received as a toast on the client. Are there any examples of somebody doing this successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get it working by using `MessageStructure`. Setting the value to `json` and updating `Message` to have a message specifically for WNS did the trick. My assumption is that the WNS value for `MessageAttributes` only applies if a message is defined specifically for WNS.

```cs
var request = new PublishRequest()
{
    TopicArn = TOPIC_ARN,
    Message = "{ \"default\": \"default message\", \"WNS\" : \"raw message\"}",
    MessageAttributes = new Dictionary<string, MessageAttributeValue>()
    {
        { "AWS.SNS.MOBILE.WNS.Type", new MessageAttributeValue() { StringValue = "wns/raw", DataType = "String" } }
    },
    MessageStructure = "json",
};
```